# Pandas Replace original column null values with df.apply results

Tags: python, pandas

I have below dataframe `df`, where `stamp B` are null sometimes. Have to fill such null values with date of `Stamp A` and respective time from the `Time` column

```
              stamp A             stamp B      Time
0 2012-10-08 18:15:05 2012-10-08 18:15:05  19:00:01
1 2012-10-09 12:15:05                 NaT  18:45:09
2 2012-10-11 18:13:00                 NaT  12:20:20
3 2012-10-11 08:15:15 2012-10-11 18:15:05  22:10:05
4 2012-10-12 18:15:20 2012-10-12 17:10:20  19:34:12
```

Here is my solution -

```
>>>from datetime import dateime as dtm    
>>>result = df[df['stamp B'].isnull()].apply(lambda x: dtm.combine(x['stamp A'].date(), dtm.strptime(x["Time"], "%H:%M:%S").time()), axis=1)
```

It returns `result` as below:

```
1   2012-10-09 18:45:09
2   2012-10-11 12:20:20
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But not sure, how to replace this `result` with`NaT` values in the original dataframe `df['stamp B']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandaspydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove times and add timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and then replace missing values by [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
dates = df['stamp A'].dt.floor('d').add(pd.to_timedelta(df['Time']))
df['stamp B'] = df['stamp B'].combine_first(dates)

print (df)
              stamp A             stamp B      Time
0 2012-10-08 18:15:05 2012-10-08 18:15:05  19:00:01
1 2012-10-09 12:15:05 2012-10-09 18:45:09  18:45:09
2 2012-10-11 18:13:00 2012-10-11 12:20:20  12:20:20
3 2012-10-11 08:15:15 2012-10-11 18:15:05  22:10:05
4 2012-10-12 18:15:20 2012-10-12 17:10:20  19:34:12
```

Answer (score 3):

I would extract the date from `stamp A`, add the `Time`, then do a `fillna` on `stamp B`:

```
s = df['stamp A'].dt.normalized() + pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])

df['stamp B'] = df['stamp B'].fillna(s)
```